# Why consumption is defined as $ C_t:= \left(\int^1_0C_t(i)^{\frac{\epsilon-1}{\epsilon}}di\right)^{\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon-1}} $

Tags: macroeconomics, consumption, new-keynesian-economics

I am reading ***Monetary policy, inflation, and the business cycle: an introduction to the new Keynesian framework and its applications*** by Gali.

In section 3.1 he presents/defines the consumption as
$$
C_t:= \left(\int^1_0C_t(i)^{\frac{\epsilon-1}{\epsilon}}di\right)^{\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon-1}}
$$

$\epsilon$ is the elasticity of substitution and $i$ indexes the goods available for consumption. It is related to the New Keynesian Model.

**Can someone give me *verbal* explanation of why it make sense to define the consumption this way?**

$C_t(i):$ How should interpret the $i$-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason Ubiquitous edited this information into the question, rather posting it as an answer:

> $i$ indexes the goods available for consumption

Integrals are just sums with a lot of components (technically infinite). Here the space of goods is assumed to have large dimension, rather than just consisting of two or three types of goods.